# where are the logs stored in TFS2017

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2017 in Windows server 2016. I just want to know the following

1. where are the installation logs stored in server?
2. Where are the transaction/history logs stored in server?

Correct me if am wrong, is it possible to backup history of logs and attach to TFS upgrade [in case of TFS version upgrade]?

Comment: Logs are purely informational. What is the exact information you're after? I don't understand why you're asking this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The installation log file generally store in `temp` folder.

Typically this folder is : `C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Temp`

And the Configuration logs stored in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs
```

The logs should be stored accordingly in case of TFS version upgrade.

Please refer to below articles for details(Even documented with old version of TFS and it's still apply for the new versions):

- [Where to find the TFS installation log?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emmamou/2010/01/17/where-to-find-the-tfs-installation-log/)
- [I’m having problems with TFS install/upgrade/repair/uninstall –
  where are the log files?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmanning/2007/07/21/im-having-problems-with-tfs-installupgraderepairuninstall-where-are-the-log-files/)
- [Trace/logging configuration in Team Foundation Server 11](http://larzjoakimnilzzon.blogspot.com/2012/04/tracelogging-configuration-in-team.html)

Comment: Thanks Andy....I found Configuration logs but could not find installation logs folder temp in C:\...\ Local

Comment: I want to know TFS application logs(who used TFS,timestamp,..) and where are the regarding TFS changesets stored? Please help

Comment: @Shalem You may want to check the OI `http://server:8080/tfs/_oi/_diagnostics/activityLog`