# How do we find the TFS logs?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

How do we find the TFS logs? I need to extract those logs and export/bind them to my new TFS server.

How can we extract and attach the TFS logs?

Comment: Do you mean how to migrate the whole version history?

Comment: Yes, version history

Comment: Do you mean to Source Code history?

Comment: Is Source Code history & Activity Log different? Where is this Source code history found/traced?

Comment: Do you use TFVC or GIT? the source code history is different from activity log.

Comment: I'm using TFVC now

Comment: @Shayki - Any update?

Comment: Look like you find the answer, you accepted the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the activity logs over provided url. Similar query over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845585/where-are-the-logs-stored-in-tfs2017)

http://server:8080/tfs/_oi/_diagnostics/activityLog

You can use export option on selecting host [collection/project], it downloads the logs in CSV format. I believe you can attach/import it to your new server